# List destructor causing crash in thread-local singleton class

Tags: c++, list, c++11, mingw, thread-local-storage

I've tried to create thread-local singleton class with member of `std::list` type. During tests with multiple threads, I've encountered segfault caused by `std::list` destructor (more precisely, `_M_clear()` method invoked by destructor). It happens even without performing any operations on mentioned list.

Any ideas, what can be problem here?

Below is minimal example to repreduce this error:

```
#include <list>
#include <thread>

class tls_list_test
{
private:
    std::list<int> test_list;

    tls_list_test() = default;

    ~tls_list_test() = default;

public:
    static tls_list_test& get_instance()
    {
        thread_local tls_list_test instance;
        return instance;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<std::thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::thread thread([]()
           {
               auto& instance = tls_list_test::get_instance();
           });
        threads.push_back(std::move(thread));
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads)
    {
        thread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Code in `std::list` causing segfault:

```
  template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
    void
    _List_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::
    _M_clear() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    {
      typedef _List_node<_Tp>  _Node;
      __detail::_List_node_base* __cur = _M_impl._M_node._M_next;
      while (__cur != &_M_impl._M_node)
    {
      _Node* __tmp = static_cast<_Node*>(__cur);
      __cur = __tmp->_M_next; // <- SEGFAULT on this line
      _Tp* __val = __tmp->_M_valptr();
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      _Node_alloc_traits::destroy(_M_get_Node_allocator(), __val);
#else
      _Tp_alloc_type(_M_get_Node_allocator()).destroy(__val);
#endif
      _M_put_node(__tmp);
    }
    }
```

GDB Variables:

```
Signal = SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
__tmp = {std::__cxx11::_List_base<int, std::allocator>::_Node * | 0xfeeefeeefeeefeee} 0xfeeefeeefeeefeee
__val = {int * | 0x2ee4448} 0x2ee4448
this = {std::__cxx11::_List_base<int, std::allocator> * const | 0x2ee5be8} 0x2ee5be8
__cur = {std::__detail::_List_node_base * | 0xfeeefeeefeeefeee} 0xfeeefeeefeeefeee
```

G++ version:

`g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`

Comment: Should be MinGW, cause every other compiler works fine for me

Comment: Did you try printing the address of each `instance`? Your code seems correct in any case.

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes, every instance has different address

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason is the implementation of `thread_local` on your compiler. The local variable is not (implied) `static`. Try adding `static` to the (local) variable:

```
static thread_local tls_list_test instance;
```

Comment: I tried it. static makes no difference in this case.

Comment: A quick search on mingw-w64's bugtrackers seems to confirm it's a compiler problem: [thread_local stl object's destructor causing crash](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/527/) / [Crash during destruction of thread_local objects](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/727/)

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91757) in all gcc versions prior to 8.4 in handling function local `thread_local`.

Use a newer gcc version or use a class static or namespace scoped `thread_local` instead.